# Fetch post meta in the same query as the main loop

Tags: custom-post-types, pre-get-posts

I have a custom post type "staff" and each as a custom field "_staff_purpose" (describing its function).

I would like that the archive-staff.php template display all staff members, sorted by their _staff_purpose, so that i can then loop through the result using the _staff_purpose as a heading.
The result i'd like to have is like this:

```
ID  |   post_title    |  _staff_purpose
-----------------------------------------
1   |   Tracy Chap.   |  administrator
-----------------------------------------
2   |   John Doe.     |  teacher
-----------------------------------------
3   |   Robert Smith  |  teacher
-----------------------------------------
```

The raw SQL should be this:

```
SELECT * FROM `bj_posts` p

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT post_id, meta_value as purpose
    FROM `bj_postmeta` pm 
    WHERE  `meta_key`='purpose'
    ) pm ON p.ID=pm.post_id
WHERE p.`post_type`='staff' AND p.`post_status`='publish'
ORDER BY purpose ASC, post_title ASC
```

I've tried this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'fetch_staff_people' );

function fetch_staff_people( $query )
{

    if ( is_page_template('archive-staff.php') && $query->is_main_query() )
    {
        $query->set( 'post_per_page', '-1' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_staff_purpose' );
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value title'); // sort by purpose, then by staff name.
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC ASC' );


        } else { 

          return;
        }

    return $query;
}
```

The query seems to work but the custom field value does not appear in the loop.

Comment: You need to show us your loop code.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Do you want to fetch the post meta in the main query so its value is stored in the $post object used in [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)? I think you can't using WP Query, so you can't do it in the `preg_get_posts` action hook.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i want.

Comment: To access the meta data use `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_staff_purpose', true );` in your loop. Note also the double sorting will work in this instance as you're sorting ASC.

Comment: @bonger that would trigger a sql query for each entry in the loop. That's what i want to avoid. In the end, i've used a raw sql query with get_results().

Comment: No, counter-intuitively, it doesn't, as WP caches all the meta data behind your back when you do a query, so using `get_post_meta` is the de rigueur way of doing things in WP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use double sorting option. You can try this code once:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'fetch_staff_people' );
function fetch_staff_people( $query )
{
  if ( is_post_type_archive('staff') && $query->is_main_query() )
  {
    $query->set( 'post_per_page', '-1' );
    $query->set( 'meta_key', '_staff_purpose' );
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num'); // sort by purpose, then by staff name.
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
  }
}
```

**Note:** I used the `is_post_type_archive()` function in the conditional tag. It is checking the archive page. See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive)

Comment: the double sorting I can live without. It's the inclusion of the meta_key in the sql results that I'm seeking to know how to do. I've now included the raw SQL that i would like to express in Wordpress' query logic.